# Alpha / Transparency & MTKView?

Tags: swift, metal, alpha, mtkview

I have a Metal fragment shader that returns some transparent colors with an alpha channel and I'd like to reveal a UIView under the MTKView, but they only background result I get is black and "error noise".

MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor:

```
pipelineStateDescriptor.isAlphaToCoverageEnabled = true
pipelineStateDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].pixelFormat = .bgra8Unorm
pipelineStateDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].isBlendingEnabled = true
pipelineStateDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].destinationRGBBlendFactor = .oneMinusSourceAlpha
pipelineStateDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].destinationAlphaBlendFactor = .oneMinusSourceAlpha
```

MTLRenderPassDescriptor:

```
renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].loadAction = .clear
renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].clearColor = MTLClearColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0)
```

If I change the clear color I can see it under the transparent colors, tho if I skip the clear color I see "error noise". Does the clear color alpha channel actually do anything?

Does anyone know how to make a MTKView transparent?

**Update:**

Here's the magical property to make a MTKView transparent:

```
self.isOpaque = false
```

Comment: Are you using a subclass of `MTKView` which overrides the `opaque` property to return false?

Comment: The isOpaque property did it! Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If a `UIView` may have transparent content or otherwise fail to fill itself with opaque drawing, then it should set its `opaque` (`isOpaque`) property to false so that it will be properly composited with whatever is behind it. Since, `MTKView` is a subclass of `UIView`, this applies to it as well.

Answer (score 2):

First you should change the opaque of the window.
Then you should locate the MTKView instance, and modify its layer's opaque to NO. That should work.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear
{
    [_view.window setOpaque:NO];
    _view.window.backgroundColor = [NSColor clearColor];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    MTKView *view = (MTKView *)self.view;
    view.layer.opaque = NO;
}
```